# Random walker using Processing.JS on Khan Academy, with new walkers generated on mouse click

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, processing.js

I've created a project on Khan Academy as part of the Natural Simulations course on [random walks](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming-natural-simulations/programming-randomness/a/random-walks).

This project is in JavaScript, using the [Processing.JS](http://processingjs.org/) library, slightly modified by Khan Academy.

(In the main, the inclusion of the Processing.JS library offers a few functions for drawing on a canvas. The majority of my project would be perfectly intelligible to someone who knew JavaScript but not about Processing.JS).

The code is as follows:

```js
var Walker = function(colour, x, y) {
    this.radius = 10;
    this.x = x || width/2; // 'width' and 'height' refer to the size of the canvas
    this.y = y || height/2;
    this.r = (colour[0] === 0)? true: colour[0] || random(0, 255);
    this.g = (colour[1] === 0)? true: colour[1] || random(0, 255);
    this.b = (colour[2] === 0)? true: colour[2] || random(0, 255);
    return this;
};

// Randomly move up, down, left, right, or stay in one place
Walker.prototype.walk = function() {
    var choice = floor(random(0, 4));
    if (choice === 0 && this.x < width) {
        this.x += this.radius; // move right
    } else if (choice === 1 && this.x > 0) {
        this.x -= this.radius; // move left
    } else if (choice === 2 && this.y < height) {
        this.y += this.radius; // move down
    } else if (choice === 3 && this.y > 0) {
        this.y -= this.radius; // move up
    }
    return this;
};

Walker.prototype.display = function() { // Processing.JS drawing stuff
    noStroke(); // turn outline off
    fill(this.r, this.g, this.b, 20); // fill(r, g, b, transparency);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.radius); // ellipse(x-position, y-position, width, height);
    return this;
};

var walkers = [new Walker([255, 0, 0])];

draw = function() { // repeats 30 times/second. Like a for/while loop, but slower
    for(var i = 0; i < walkers.length; i++) {
        walkers[i].walk().display();
    }
};

mouseClicked = function() {
    walkers.push(
        new Walker([], round(mouseX / walkers[0].radius) * walkers[0].radius, round(mouseY / walkers[0].radius) * walkers[0].radius));
}; // ^ mouseX/mouseY refer to current position of mouse on canvas
```

View the project on [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/semi-transparent-random-blobber/4514090567467008).

I'm concerned about the performance of this code; specifically the `for` loop in the `draw` function. As the `draw` function repeats 30 times/second, will this mean that the loop will also repeat 30 times/second?

The program gets pretty slow when there's quite a few walkers initiated. How can I make this program perform better?

Answer (score 1):

I would put `noStroke` in a different location.

You are trying to make this code more efficient. You call `noStroke` each time one of these guys is called. You really only need to call it once right? So change the state once in your `draw` function:

```
draw = function() {
    noStroke();
    for(var i = 0; i < walkers.length; i++) {
        walkers[i].walk().display();
    }
};
```

And remove it from your `Walker.display` function:

```
Walker.prototype.display = function() {
    fill(this.r, this.g, this.b, 20);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.radius);
    return this;
};
```